# Evaluating derivatives with respect to certain vector axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, differentiation

So, I am trying to work in Spherical coordinates. I have a predefined fixed axis, $\hat{v}_0$, so that $\alpha=\vec{r}.\hat{v}_0$ Now, I am interested in the following:
\begin{equation}
f(r,\alpha)=\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \alpha}\frac{\sin(kr)}{r}.
\end{equation}

How do I find $f(r,\alpha)$? I have no clue how to proceed?

Comment: Can't you just use $\partial_\alpha = \hat{v}_0 \cdot \vec{\nabla}$?

Comment: But, how would I deal with the $\partial_i\partial_j$ part after carrying out $\hat{v}_o.\left(\vec{\nabla}(\sin(kr)/r)\right)$?